# I have two functions, which are identical except for one constant array value

Tags: c++

I have two functions, which are identical except for one constant array value. A ternary statement does the job but conceptually nothing is 'conditional' on anything; they're two different functions! This doesn't extend well to when there are more than two variants of a function because if scopes variables so you can't set them to const.

```
    inline int function(const bool the_diagonal_version) {
        // do something
        const int orthogonal[4][2] = {{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}};
        const int diagonal[4][2] = {{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,1},{-1,-1}};
        const auto directions = the_diagonal_version?diagonal:orthogonal;

        // use these directions, maybe even in a function that overloads/enable_ifs for const/non-const.
        return 0;
    }
```

Is there some clever trick with the newfangled constexpr if ? Alternatively is there some hellscape SFINAE solution that at least helps me avoid duplicating code?

Comment: Not _entirely_ sure what you're trying to accomplish with the code or two functions. We don't know what "_the job_" refers to... Brief us to your background problem first. (See [ask] for more info.)

Comment: Wild guess; a template function?

Comment: Make third function taking this array as parameter and containing real implementation while old two functions call this new function supplying appropriate array.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. `the_diagonal_version` is a condition knows at compiler time or run time? What do you mean by _This doesn't extend well to when there are more than two variants of a function because if scopes variables so you can't set them to const._?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a mountain out of a molehill

```
int function(bool value)
{
     const int data[2][4][2] = {{{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}},
                                {{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,1},{-1,-1}}
                               };
     const int (&directions)[4][2] = data[value];

      // whatever, using directions
}
```

Optionally, `data` can be `static` if desired.   This solution has no duplication of code, can be extended as desired to any integral type (with appropriate range checking if needed).

Alternatives might be

```
 int function_internal(const int (&directions)[4][2])
 {
     // whatever, using directions
 }

 int function(bool value)
 {
     const int data[2][4][2] = {{{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}},
                                {{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,1},{-1,-1}}
                               };
     const int (&directions)[4][2] = data[value];
     return function_internal(directions);
 }
```

or even

```
 int function(bool value)
 {
     const int data[2][4][2] = {{{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}},
                                {{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,1},{-1,-1}}
                               };
     return function_internal(data[value]);
 }
```

or, as a template (which I consider to be over-kill)

```
 template<bool value> int function();

 template<> int function<false>()
 {
       return function_internal({{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}});
 }

 template<> int function<true>()
 {
       return function_internal({1,1},{1,-1},{-1,1},{-1,-1}});
 }

 // call as function<true>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have the parameter as a template?

```
template<bool the_diagonal_version>
constexpr int function() {
        // do something
        const int orthogonal[4][2] = {{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}};
        const int diagonal[4][2] = {{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,1},{-1,-1}};
        const auto directions = the_diagonal_version?diagonal:orthogonal;

        // use these directions, maybe even in a function that overloads/enable_ifs for const/non-const.
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What did you accomplish with this template? How is it better than passing the `bool` as an argument to a normal function?

Comment: Actually it is not an improvement if you are using constexpr, but it might be helpful in previous versions of the compiler. Because you can help the compiler optimize the code.